# Where do i apply analyzers and token filters in elasticsearch while indexing documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

I am trying to implement an analyzer (uppercase) and index some documents after that in elasticsearch. My question is, am i following the correct procedure?

```
Implement your analyzer (containing index and type name), which would create the index if it doesnt exist

Then index the documents with the same index and type name as above during which stream of text would pass through the analyzer and then would be saved in index.
```

Is this the correct way to go about it?

I indexed some documents with and without using analyzers, checked the contents of index before/after using *Facets*, and they were no different.

Answer (score 0):

The content is not supposed to be different. How it's indexed is. You should recognize the difference because queries would have different results, like some documents are found which weren't without the analyzers, and viceversa.

Try for instance a [March Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-match-query.html).

The `_score` may and should also change

Comment: OK...so '_score' and different results are two parameters....Any other way i can get to know index has changed?

Comment: You can get the mapping  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html. That will tell you what analyzers are being used